# Port forwarding through VPN using docker

Tags: vpn, port, docker

I am new to docker and have set it up for my work VPN but want to know if I have gone about it in a sensible way.

First I created an image that runs openvpn client and connects to work.

Second I created an image that would ssh to my work network. I used the --network option to point at my first image.

This gets me into work fine. Next I wanted to be able to connect to VNC on my remote machine. I could forward the VNC port back to my second image but I could not expose the port as i was using --network.

Instead i exposed the port on the first image which felt a bit wrong but does work.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run the VPN in a container?

Comment: Yes. I want to then only expose some network traffic through this docker.